# Google Sheets Script:Group Button At Bottom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, grouping

I'm populating a new sheet with parsed data from another sheet, and then I group rows using shiftRowGroupDepth().

It works well, but I was surprised to find all the group/ungroup buttons at the **bottom** of a group instead of the top.

I've checked the Group Class in the docs, but I haven't found a method to revert to the default - button at top. Anyone know where this setting is?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in another forum, it's:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setRowGroupControlPosition(SpreadsheetApp.GroupControlTogglePosition.BEFORE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty straight forward. Just right click on the + / - Icon and click "Move  +/-" button to the top"

[image: Move +/-" button to the top]

Comment: This would be a repetitive, manual solution. The question requires a script solution.